# Copy data from one class instance to another class instance having same property names but different property types

Tags: c#

I have two classes with same property names but different types,
that is,one class with **string** properties and another class with properties of **user defined type**,
i want to copy data from one class to another,
so,is it possible??
Please suggest a solution

Thanks and regards.

Comment: What did you try? If you don't show your code, it's hard to see what goes wrong.

Comment: You've given us nowhere near enough information to even start to answer this. For a start, it would depend entirely on the nature of this user-defined type; if said type has an implicit cast operator from string, or a constructor that takes a single string, then it's simple. If not, then we have absolutely no information on which to base an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't expect the .net framework to be able to do everything for you. Create a method that takes the source class as an argument, creates an instance of the destination class, copies the properties across (mapping and converting as only you know how) and returns the new object.

Comment: Thanks, I was just taking a chance.